# Android : SystemUI process memory consumption shoot up

Tags: android, performance, android-memory, android-framework

> I am developing a custom ROM where i have added some customizations
>   into SystemUI.apk. My platform provider is FreeScale.

- Now when i keep my device ON for say more than 14 hours i found that com.android.systemui process takes total memory of =~ 102 MB which is not normal.
- Please see below screesnshot of meminfo dump of systemui process.
- Can anyone assist or give some directions on how do i investigate to find the cause of this memory shoot up.

[image]

Comment: I am also interested to see the answer. Few months back i was also facing this issue while developing the custom ROM. There are some tools with which you can check the performance of your process here - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html. i hope this helps you

Comment: Funny think my `com.android.systemui` is using 103 MB (close to ~102 MB @ your device). I'm running cyanogen mod 10.2.1

Comment: I am facing the same issue that `systemui` consumes a lot of memory. Is there way to fix it? Or Do we know what cause the issue?